# why is my custom annotation on interface not available through reflection

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations

I am using Spring Data to access a Mongo database in a Spring Boot application. I'm doing this by extending MongoRepository.

```java
@CrudPublishingRepository
public interface ProfileRepository extends MongoRepository<Profile, String> {

    Optional<Profile> findByUserName(String userName);

    @Query("{'products.contracts.contractId': ?0}")
    List<Profile> findByContractId(String contractId);
}
```

For some of my repositories (including the ProfileRepository above) I need to perform some actions every time a save or delete action is performed, which is why I created the @CrudPublishingRepository annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
public @interface CrudPublishingRepository {}
```

I have used Spring AOP to intercept all save and delete methods on Spring's CrudRepository, with the following advices:

```java
@AfterReturning("execution(public * delete(..)) && this(org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository)")
public void onDeleteExecuted(JoinPoint pjp) {
    onDelete(pjp);
}

@AfterReturning("execution(public * deleteById(..)) && this(org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository)")
public void onDeleteByIdExecuted(JoinPoint pjp) {
    onDeleteById(pjp);
}

@AfterReturning("execution(public * deleteAll(..)) && this(org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository)")
public void onDeleteAllExecuted(JoinPoint pjp) {
    onDeleteAll(pjp);
}

@Around(value = "execution(public * save(..)) && this(org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository)")
public Object onSaveExecuted(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    return onSave(pjp);
}
```

the onSave method looks like this:

```java
private Object onSave(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(getTopicName(pjp));
    try {
        Object result = pjp.proceed();
        return result;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw t;
    }
}
```

And at last, the getTopicName(JoinPoint pjp) function, which is where the problem is:

```java
private Optional<String> getTopicName(JoinPoint pjp) {
    Class clazz = pjp.getTarget().getClass();
    while (clazz != null) {
        for (Class i : pjp.getTarget().getClass().getInterfaces()) {
            if (i.getAnnotation(CrudPublishingRepository.class) != null) {
                return Optional.of("found it!");
            }
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

The implementation obviously isn't finished yet, but I would expect it to return Optional.of("found it!"), but it doesn't.

When I debug, I can see that ProfileRepository is one of the interfaces, as expected, but getAnnotations() returns an empty array.

Can anyone offer me a solution or an explanation as to why this is not working?

Comment: Is `Class i : pjp.getTarget().getClass().getInterfaces()` correct, or did you mean `Class i : clazz.getInterfaces()`?

Comment: Your comment makes sense, in that it should have been like that. However, that was not the problem, since I've now gone back to only looping over the interfaces of the target class of the joinpoint.

Somehow, It started working, although I didn't make any changes that would explain why it works now, and didn't work before.

My best guess is that IntelliJ or maven were acting up, or maven and gradle weren't playing together nicely. (The aspect stuff is in a maven library used by the profile microservice, which is a gradle project)